# RVest: How to fix 'Replacement has length zero' in a loop

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

i would like to scrape a specific bit of html-code out of a website. The desired object isn't on every page of the loop below, therefore, some values are NA. But whenever an object is missing, the whole loop stops.

I tried this code for non-loop scraping, which turned out to work perfectly.
Here i excluded all values that are either unobtainable or not of interest.

`BJ <- data.frame(
  Wohnungs_ID = ID,
  Baujahr = ifelse (nchar(Baujahr)==0 | nchar(Baujahr)>6, NA, Baujahr),
  stringsAsFactors = F`

In the relevant case, i want to scrape two specific variables, that are not always listed. Url is the list of reflinks i scraped ealier.

```
library(rvest)  
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)  
library(ggplot2) 
library(stringr) 
library(jsonlite) 
library(purrr)  
library(dplyr)  

immo_webp <- read_html ("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-2/Wohnung-Miete/Rheinland-Pfalz/Koblenz")


# URLs 

base = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/'

urls <- sapply(read_html("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-2/Wohnung-Miete/Rheinland-Pfalz/Koblenz")%>%
                 html_nodes('article')%>%
                 html_attr('data-obid'), function (url){paste0(base, url)})
print(urls)

# ID bilden

substring(urls, 1, 1)
ID <- substring(urls, 41)

Baujahr <- c(1 : 20)
Energie <- c(1 : 20)

for (i in urls){

  aktuellewohnung <- read_html(url(i))

  Baujahr[i] <- aktuellewohnung %>%
    html_nodes("#is24-content > div.grid-item.padding-desk-right-xl.desk-two-thirds.lap-one-whole.desk-column-left.flex-item.palm--flex__order--1.lap--flex__order--1 > div.is24-ex-details.main-criteria-headline-size.two-column-layout > div.criteriagroup.flex.flex--wrap.criteria-group--spacing.padding-top-s > div.criteriagroup.criteria-group--border.criteria-group--two-columns.criteria-group--spacing > dl:nth-child(1) > dd") %>%
    html_text()
  Energie[i] <- aktuellewohnung %>%
    html_nodes("#is24-content > div.grid-item.padding-desk-right-xl.desk-two-thirds.lap-one-whole.desk-column-left.flex-item.palm--flex__order--1.lap--flex__order--1 > div.is24-ex-details.main-criteria-headline-size.two-column-layout > div.criteriagroup.flex.flex--wrap.criteria-group--spacing.padding-top-s > div.criteriagroup.criteria-group--border.criteria-group--two-columns.criteria-group--spacing > dl:nth-child(7) > dd") %>%
    html_text()  
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in Baujahr[i] <- aktuellewohnung %>% html_nodes("#is24-content > div.grid-item.padding-desk-right-xl.desk-two-thirds.lap-one-whole.desk-column-left.flex-item.palm--flex__order--1.lap--flex__order--1 > div.is24-ex-details.main-criteria-headline-size.two-column-layout > div.criteriagroup.flex.flex--wrap.criteria-group--spacing.padding-top-s > div.criteriagroup.criteria-group--border.criteria-group--two-columns.criteria-group--spacing > dl:nth-child(1) > dd") %>%  : 

replacement has length zero
```

I want this loop to continue and save the missing value as NA.
Hopefully, you can help me. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test this since you didn't provide urls for a true reprex, but I think wrapping your code in some try() functions should work.

```
for (i in urls){

  aktuellewohnung <- read_html(url(i))

  Baujahr[i] <- aktuellewohnung %>%
    try(html_nodes("#is24-content > div.grid-item.padding-desk-right-xl.desk-two-thirds.lap-one-whole.desk-column-left.flex-item.palm--flex__order--1.lap--flex__order--1 > div.is24-ex-details.main-criteria-headline-size.two-column-layout > div.criteriagroup.flex.flex--wrap.criteria-group--spacing.padding-top-s > div.criteriagroup.criteria-group--border.criteria-group--two-columns.criteria-group--spacing > dl:nth-child(1) > dd")) %>%
    try(html_text())
  Energie[i] <- aktuellewohnung %>%
    try(html_nodes("#is24-content > div.grid-item.padding-desk-right-xl.desk-two-thirds.lap-one-whole.desk-column-left.flex-item.palm--flex__order--1.lap--flex__order--1 > div.is24-ex-details.main-criteria-headline-size.two-column-layout > div.criteriagroup.flex.flex--wrap.criteria-group--spacing.padding-top-s > div.criteriagroup.criteria-group--border.criteria-group--two-columns.criteria-group--spacing > dl:nth-child(7) > dd")) %>%
    try(html_text())  
}
```

Comment: I added the required code to execute the code manually. When using your fix, i get the following error: ``` number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length ``` Maybe the added code helps you to solve my problem :) thanks a lot in advance –